# Deleting a custom doubly linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, destructor

List Property:
one pointer pointing to the next node and the other pointer to any arbitrary node in the list.

**Structure**

```
struct node
{
    int val;
    node* link[2];
    node(int x);
    ~node();
};
node :: node(int x)
{
    val = x;
    link[0] = NULL;
    link[1] = NULL;
}
node :: ~node()
    {
        delete(link[0]);
        delete(link[1]);
    }
```

**Class**

```
class List
{
    node *head, *cloneHead;
    node *stack[100];
    int childIndex[2][100];
    int stptr;
public:
    List();
    ~List();
    void createList(int[] , int[][2], int );
    int createListStruct(node*);
    void createCloneList();
    void clone();
    void printClone();
};
```

**Creating the list**

```
void List::createList(int a[], int child[][2], int size)
{
    node* linkedList[size];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        linkedList[i] = new node(a[i]);
    }
    head = linkedList[0];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            if(child[i][j]!=-1)
            {
                linkedList[i]->link[j] = linkedList[child[i][j]];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
int main()
{
    int a[]={10,1,3,7,2,8,20};
    int child[][2] = {{1,4},{1,2},{3,-1},{6,5},{6,5},{-1,0},{5,5}};
    int size = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    List L;
    L.createList(a,child,size);
    L.clone();
    L.printClone();
    return 0;
}
```

in normal circumstances the destructor work perfectly but for list with the above List property its failing

eg:

Node : 1

Link1 : Node 2

Link2 : Node 3

Node : 2

Link1 : Node 3

Link2 : Node 1

in the above case by the time destructor reaches Link2 of Node2, which point to node 1, node 1 is already deleted, so the code is throwing segmentation error.

I came up with : have a array of unique nodes in list and delete one by one

Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: I do not have all information about the way you build your list. Thus, I can't give a precise answer, but why are you deleting the the second link pointer? Seems like you are freeing nodes multiple times.

Comment: Its a different case, if the second link is the only thing that point to the particular node.

Comment: Are there multiple nodes that are not the next node of some other nodes (apart from the first node, which obviously is not, unless you are considering a circular list). In that case the shared_ptr, weak_ptr answer does not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared_ptr's and they will release memory when the last pointer become destroyed or reassigned. The only thing you have to remember is to avoid cycles, thats why for arbitrary node ponter use weak_ptr instead.

```
struct node; // forward declaration

struct node
{
    int val;
    shared_ptr<node> next;
    weak_ptr<node> other;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

2 alternatives to your list idea (which seems ok)

1. For each Node keep a list of the parents. When a node gets deleted, set all the parents their pointers to that node to `nullptr`. You can safely delete a `nullptr` as often as you like.
2. If your graph is a tree (i.e. without cycles) you can use reference counting using either shared pointers or unique_pointers

Comment: The parent would have been deleted by the time, so if I try to set the link to null then it will be a segmentation fault error.

Comment: As the destructors are called recursively, the parent is still (but barely) alive when the destructors of its child nodes are called. The memory containing the pointers is most definitely still allocated.

Comment: I want to know is there any option without using any extra space